# Sustainable Solution To Configuring Rails, Sidekiq, Redis All On AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq, amazon-elasticache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk rails app that needs a sidekiq worker processes running alongside Puma/Passenger.  Getting the sidekiq process to run has resulted in hours failed attempts.  Also, getting the rails app and sidekiq to talk to my AWS ElastiCache cluster apparently needs some security rule changes.

#### Background

We started out with an extremely simple Rails app that was easily deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  Since those early times we've evolved the app to now use the worker framework Sidekiq.  Sidekiq in turn likes to use Redis to pull its jobs.  Anyway, getting all these puzzle pieces assembled in the AWS world is a little challenging.

Answer (score 6):

#### Solutions From The Web...with some sustainability problems

The AWS ecosystem goes through updates and upgrades, many aren't documented with clarity.  For example environment settings change regularly; a script you have written may break in subsequent versions.

I used the following smattering of solutions to try to solve this:

- http://blog.noizeramp.com/2013/04/21/using-sidekiq-with-elastic-beanstalk/ (please note that the comments in this blog post contains a number of helpful gists).  Many thanks to the contributor and commenters in this post.
- http://qiita.com/sawanoboly/items/d28a05d3445901cf1b25 (starting sidekiq with upstart/initctl seems like the simplest and most sustainable approach).  This page is in japanese, but the sidekiq startup code makes complete sense.  Thanks!
- Use AWS's ElastiCache for Redis.  Make sure to configure your security groups accordingly: [this AWS document was helpful...](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.AuthorizeAccess.html#GettingStarted.AuthorizeAccess.VPC)

Comment: I'll update and compelte this answer when I have some time.  I'll be sure to include version numbers and some gists.

Comment: Awesome initiative. Do beware of link rot though.

Comment: I would add this more recent article to this list: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mDI034zEIceus4u0n5yBc75t-A6DkUqxg571qwd-Puc/edit#

Comment: The [second option](http://qiita.com/sawanoboly/items/d28a05d3445901cf1b25), although in japanese, works better than any other scripts i've seen so far.